# Download de múltiplos arquivos do Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-aws

## Situação

Tenho centenas (e até milhares) de arquivos pequenos (~50KB) no Amazon S3 separados em buckets por dia.

## Problema

Preciso fazer download através da minha aplicação Java entregando para o front-end de todos os arquivos de determinado período. Minha máquina no Cloud é limitada de recursos de memória e disco (possui 2GB de memória RAM e 5GB de disco).

## Solução 1

Baixar um a um os arquivos e repassá-los para o front-end? Solução um tanto quanto ineficiente, já que trata-se de milhares de arquivos pequenos.

## Solução 2

Baixar um a um os arquivos e compactar em zip (considerando os limites da máquina, quebrando o zip em partes se for o caso) e fazer upload deste zip para o Amazon S3, entregando para o front apenas o link do zip.

## Pergunta

Existe outra solução que alguém já usou, algum recurso nativo da AWS ou alguma idéia mais eficiente para resolver este problema?

Comment: Acredito que sua solução esta aqui : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764836/amazon-s3-console-download-multiple-files-at-once utilizando o AWS CLI vocẽ tem essa opçao de baixar vários arquivos.

Comment: Por quê não só fornecer os links do S3 para o frontend dos arquivos dentro do período desejado? A aplicação não precisará baixar nada e o cliente poderá acessar qual arquivo necessitar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem o problema seria desempenho, algumas coisas que acredito que podem ajudar:

1- Usar uma função para já deixar o zip pronto:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

2- Entregar pro cliente via CloudFront (CDN):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html

3- Entregar via BitTorrent:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html

4- Usar a classe TransferManager para baixar em paralelo:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html

5- Evitar usar arquivos tão pequenos, talvez agregar em lotes maiores com lambda ou glue.

Entregar direto pelo S3/CloudFront é melhor em termos de custo, desempenho e segurança.